# How to limit a calculated value to a specific ceiling

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have a table I need to calculate some data from, which looks like this:

```
id             count          CreateDate                 completeddate
1              4000        2014-02-05 00:41:13.943    2014-02-05 00:41:14.293
1              1490        2014-02-05 00:41:49.880    2014-02-05 01:36:03.547
1               10         2014-02-05 00:48:42.350    2014-02-05 00:48:42.530
1             50000        2014-02-05 00:56:00.217    2014-02-05 00:56:00.347
```

And I am running this query on it:

```
with edc (id, count, createdate, completeddate)
as 
(select id, count, CreateDate, completeddate from edch with (nolock) where id = 1)
select 
    (cast(sum(count) as float) / sum(cast((completeddate - createdate) as float) * 24)) as [Estimated Max Throughput], 
    sum(cast((completeddate - createdate) as float) * 24) as [Total Hours],
    convert(date, createdate) as [Day]
from edc 
where createdate > '2014-09-01 00:00:00.000' 
and completeddate is not null 
and (count > 500 or DATEDIFF(MM, createdate, completeddate) > 1)
group by convert(date, createdate)
order by [Day] desc
go
```

This query basically runs through the table for a specific date range, aggregates the totals, and then calculates a theoretical maximum per hour if the system is not maxed out (ie only ran for 20 minutes) or the actual maximum if it ran for > 1 hour. Its working fine and my output is as expected, except in a scenario where I have a CreateDate and CompletedDate that are more than 1 full day apart. Those values are normal and are expected in the dataset, so I need to find some way to normalize them.

What I think is a good solution is to have

```
sum(cast((completeddate - actiondate) as float) * 24)
```

cut off at 24 (ie, if it returns 80, use 24 instead). Problem is I cant figure out how to do that. I tried searching but Floor() and Ceiling() dont do what I need, and most of the keywords I try to search with return results about finding the max and min volumes from a column.

I am sure there is a simple command I can use I just have been unable to find it.

This is all t-sql btw, I cannot do any processing in an app layer as there is none :)

Comment: If you take your suggested approach, you are going to miss the intervening day in your calculations.  I don't know if that is a problem for what you are doing.

Comment: Not a problem in this scenario, I /could/ just drop these values but I want to see if there is a way to include them before doing that. The problem theyre creating is the counts are very very low (like 20-30), but they span many multiple days (5 days or more). The other values I have are more like 300k in 4 or 5 minutes, so even one occurrence really skews the data. Once I figure out how to set a value for these records, I can fudge them however I like, so the hard set 24 value could be replaced with the 'normal' value of another record with a similar count or something like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using a case statement, which I dont like because it makes understanding what the code is doing fairly difficult, but it works exactly like I needed and the results are more accurate when an outlier value exists:

```
select 
(cast(sum(count) as float) / 
    (CASE 
        WHEN sum(cast((completeddate - createdate) as float) * 24) > 24 THEN cast(24 as float)
        ELSE sum(cast((completeddate - createdate) as float) * 24) 
    END)) as [Estimated Max Throughput]
```

If anyone else comes up with a nicer/cooler/better/faster solution, I will update that as the correct answer.

Comment: I had to do the same, let us know if someone finds another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using if, if(sum(cast((completeddate - actiondate) as float) * 24) > 24,24, sum(cast((completeddate - actiondate) as float) * 24))

Comment: Is this complete syntax? That throws a lot of errors when I use it. I found a man page for `IIF()`  command that uses this proposed syntax, but I cant use it because im running server 2008, not 2012, and updating is not an option.

Comment: @UnicornoMarley : You will have to include this in your query.